# Semantic-UI breaks Content Security Policy

Tags: semantic-ui, content-security-policy

Can Semantic-UI modal dialogs be used with Content Security Policy (CSP) directives but without requiring 'unsafe-inline'?

Semantic UI modals inject inline styles into the DOM. This then weakens the HTTP Content-Security-Policy header by requiring 'unsafe-inline' for styles.

Is it possible to externalize the inline styles into a stylesheet so that CSP can be used effectively?

Comment: Seems CSP deployments remain very, very low. Let than 0.5% of the web.   See CSP Survey: https://embedthis.com/blog/posts/csp-survey/